# 'operator<<(std::ostream&, int&)’ is ambiguous

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Isn't this:

```
operator<<(std::cout, 0);
```

The same as this?

```
std::cout<<0;
```

I tried this piece of code:

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    operator<<(std::cout,0);
    return 0;
}
```

But I got the following error message:

```
a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cpp:11:28: error: call of overloaded ‘operator<<(std::ostream&, int)’ is ambiguous
a.cpp:11:28: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:528:5: note: std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const unsigned char*) [with _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:523:5: note: std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const signed char*) [with _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:510:5: note: std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, const char*) [with _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/ostream.tcc:323:5: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const char*) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:473:5: note: std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, unsigned char) [with _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:468:5: note: std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, signed char) [with _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:462:5: note: std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>&, char) [with _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:456:5: note: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, char) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
```

Can someone explain it please?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is the same as:

```
std::cout.operator<<(0);
```

Using `operator<<(std::cout, 0);`  makes [Argument-Dependent Lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) (ADL) kick in, which finds multiple candidates that accept a `std::basic_ostream<char>` and an `int` (or a type that has a valid implicit conversion from `int`) as input. Once ADL kicks in, all of these various overloads become valid candidates.